# ASP.NET MVC4 IE & CHROME not storing cookies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-cookies

In my mvc4 application I create cookies for form authentication as

```
public ActionResult Login(UserLogin user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool res = System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(user.UserName, user.Password);

            if (res)
            {
                Utente utente = commonRepository.GetProfiloUtente(user.UserName);

                if (utente != null)
                {
                    Session["user"] = utente;
                }

                var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                string userData = serializer.Serialize(utente);

                DateTime dataLavorativa = commonRepository.GetGiornoLavorativoPrecedente(utente.IDInterno);

                Session["data_lavorativa"] = dataLavorativa;


                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
          user.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes), true, userData,
          FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);



                string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

                var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket)
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
                    Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
                    Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain
                };

                // Create the cookie.
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
            }
        }
        return View("Index", user);
    }
```

This works fine in FFox (if I close the browser then reopen) it's ok , in IE and Chrome I've been redirected to login page.... I've checked both and all are at lower level for security.... and accepts cookies... any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: I had similar situation and it was disabled cookies in chrome settings. Generally.. no reason why it should't work

Comment: and on ie it was working?

Comment: You aren't setting any expiry on the cookie, hence when you close the browser the cookie is being discarded. Firefox has the 'save and quit' option which persists session cookies (and all other session data) between execution, which is why that is working.
If you want your login to persist beyond browser sessions, set an actual expires (e.g. DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)) and that should work cross browser....

Comment: Hello LDJ, I'm setting this     FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
          user.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes), true, userData,
          FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);